# Incomplete graphs plotting in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink, matlab-deployment

I am having an issue running a FOC algorithm in Simulink (see image attached). Specifically, the graphs only plotted until 0.5 despite the simulation is set to 10 seconds (see image attached). Does anyone know what is happening? Thanks in advance.

The file can be found in the following MatlabExchange link:https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39605-vector-control-of-permanent-magnet-synchronous-motor-pmsm

[image: Simulation Graphs]
[image: FOC_Algorithm_Simulink]

Comment: Please always consider accepting the answer, if it was right. If not, say so and I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the rest of the timespan that is displayed. (Auto-)Zoom properly or set the scope settings according to your simulation time.

And more importantly: play around with the buttons you have available.

[image]